# Dust onLoad context always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I am working with dust.js on a server side application. I have some code that looks like this:

```
dust.onLoad = function(tmpl, ctx, cb) {
  console.log(ctx);
};

...

dust.context(null, { layout: this.layout });
console.log('context injected');
dust.stream('testTemplate', { test: true });
```

The output looks like this:

```
context injected
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `dust.context` it returns a Context for you to use later. It does not set the options you provide onto any global object.

Try passing the Context returned to your `dust.stream` call like this:

```
var ctx = dust.context(null, { layout: this.layout });
dust.stream('testTemplate', ctx.push({ test: true }));
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get context into the template. I'm trying to get context in the `dust.onLoad` function.

Comment: You can't get context into onLoad, only the global options (the second argument to context creation)